# Is debugging possible with python-click using intellij?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, python-click

This seems like a general problem with python-click, however there is no mention of it anywhere on google.

If I try run even the simplest of python click scripts, like the following from
[realpython](https://realpython.com/blog/python/comparing-python-command-line-parsing-libraries-argparse-docopt-click/)

```
import click

@click.group()
def greet():
    pass


@greet.command()
def hello(**kwargs):
    pass


@greet.command()
def goodbye(**kwargs):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    greet()
```

The Intellij debugger completely bombs with the error message:

```
Error: no such option: --multiproc
```

I have tried this with multiple python-click scripts and debugging never works. Has anyone else noticed this and is there any way around this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in PyCharm. I don't have access to IntelliJ, but if you can get your hands on a copy of PyCharm, that might be one option.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that!

Comment: @MorganThrapp Tried it on pycharm and same issue :(

Comment: What version of python? (i mean exact, not just 2 or 3)

Comment: @FrankV `Python 2.7.9` and Also shows this in the log `pydev debugger (build 162.1812.1)`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem arises when you do not pass any parameters to the click entry-point. In that situation, click asks a platform specific function to get it's args, `get_os_args()` which is unrelated to sys.argv.

The result effect is that debugger needed arguments are also passed to the click parser, effectively activating an error in click.

The solution is to explicitely pass `sys.argv[1:]` to the click entrypoint which will override the default `get_os_args()` behavior:

```
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    greet(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I ran into this when trying to debug an entry point within PyCharm (using Python 2.x on Windows).  I also found [this thread](https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/751) that points to the issues on why my specific case was failing.  The author's solution here was to `import click`  at the beginning of the script, avoiding this error.  Not totally relevant in the OP's case, but thought it might save someone some grief.